# How can I get rid of a siege?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I've just experienced a siege where the siege tag will not go away after I have killed all of the siege combatants.  Now no caravans will come to my fortress!  Is there a way to get rid of the siege tag that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a known bug and the siege tag goes away after winning another siege.

Comment: I don't have a copy of DF at work to test with (Or else I'd never get any work done...) but it seems like you might be able to set the INVADERS setting in the .ini file to NO and then load the game again.